# Making Combinations (Python)

Tags: python, for-loop, combinations

In Python, is there a better way to get the set of combinations of n elements from a k-element set than nested for loops or list comprehensions?

For example, say from the set [1,2,3,4,5,6] I want to get [(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,5),(4,6),(5,6)]. Is there a better of of making it than

```
nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
doubles=[]
for a in nums:
    for b in nums[a+1:]:
        doubles.append((a,b))
```

? It's okay if the elements of the list we end up with are sets, tuples, or lists; I just feel there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Google your exact question title and click on the first link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(combinations(nums, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: how to do this without `itertools` so that a for loop of pairs can be constructed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65665469/how-to-run-a-ij-loop-in-python-and-not-repeat-j-i-if-i-j-has-already-been

Comment: @develarist There is an equivalent code provided in docs if that helps: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 3):

The [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module has a lot of really powerful tools that can be used in situations like this.  In this case, you want [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).  Some other ones that you might find useful are [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) and [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations(range(1,7),2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1,7),2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(range(1,7),2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the itertools module

```
import itertools
alphabet = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
combos = list(itertools.combinations(alphabet, 2))
print combos
```