# Find the best approximation of a subset for a value

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I would like to get an algorithm that gives me the best approximation for a value based on subset.

Here is an example:

```
N = 45

subset = [25,10,65,9,8]

output: [25,10,9]
```

The important point is that the algorithm must give the best approximation (regardless the number of the element in the final result). The result must provide the association that gives the exact value of the nearest (but can not exceed the initial value).

Do you know an algorithm that could do that with the minimal time cost ?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: What have you tried? Are all numbers positive?

Comment: Yes there are all positive

Comment: Do you mean, the subset with a total closest to, but not bigger than the given number? And what if there are many possible subsets?

Comment: I mean that if the number is 45, the association found cannot be greater than 45.
If there are many possible subsets that give the best approximation, we just take one of them.

Comment: Do you mean that the sum of values in the output list must be as close to N?

Comment: yes exactly ! But can not exceed.

Answer (score 2):

## You cannot to do so in polynomial time (unless P=NP)

Finding out if there is a subset with sum exactly N is clearly easier than finding the subset with sum closest to N, and this former problem is called [subset-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is known to be NP-complete.

However, pseudo-polynomial time is possible. In fact, your problem is exactly equal to the [0/1 knapsack optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition) if we take the values in `subset` to be both the values in weights for the translation to knapsack. This 0/1 knapsack problem has a dynamic programming solution that runs in `O(nW)` where `n` is the number of items in `subset` and `W` is the target, which is `N` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for short lists. However performance will reduce significantly for longer lists:

```
import itertools
def closest(my_list, my_number):
    l=[]
    for i in range(1,len(my_list)+1):
        for k in itertools.combinations(my_list, i):
            l.append([k, sum(k)])
    l=[i for i in l if i[1]<=my_number]
    l.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    return l[-1]
print(closest(subset, 45)[0], closest(subset, 45)[1])
```

Output:

```
(25, 10, 9) 44
```

Comment: thank you. I try to understand the way you did. What is "itertools.combinations" ?

Comment: ok I got it ! But in the line "for k in itertools.combinations(my_list, i):" it should be "i+1" no ?

Comment: It's a function that returns all combinations of a list. Check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053070/making-combinations-python

Comment: Yes you are right, i changed the code so that it will loop over 1 to len(my_list) (included)

Comment: Ok thank you ! I I try to find out the complexity of combinations to get the total complexity of this algorithm.

Comment: @max5336 This code brute forces over every possible subset of the n given numbers, so it will have exponential complexity O(2**n).